# Uploading an image to the datastore in GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have this little set of Python code on the GAE, trying to upload an image to the datastore:

```
class UploadPage(webapp.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    self.response.out.write("""<html><body>
          <form action="/addimg" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
            <div><label>Project Name</label></div>
            <div><textarea name="title" rows="2" columns "60"></textarea></div>
            <div><label>Despcription:</label></div>
            <div><textarea name="content" rows="3" cols="60"></textarea></div>
            <div><label>Image</label></div>
            <div><input type="file" name="img"/></div>
            <div><input type="submit" value="Upload" /></div>
          </form>
        </body>
      </html>""")

class addimg(webapp.RequestHandler):
  def post(self):
    images = ImgUpload()
    imgtitle = self.request.get('title')
    imgcontent = self.request.get('content')
    headpic = self.request.get('img')
    images.headpic = db.Blob(headpic)
    images.imgtitle = imgtitle
    images.imgcontent = imgcontent
    images.put()
    self.redirect('/upload')
```

When you go to the site, hit submit, it goes to the addimg and stops and doesn't complete the put or redirect, I am not sure where I may have missed it, any guidance is very appreciative.

Comment: Can you tell what the last line in your post function getting executed is?

Comment: @jknupp the logs in the appserver only have the redirect to the post

Comment: I see no bugs in your code but it is not all the code. If you put a logging statement on every other line of `post` in class addimg you can step through the function and see where the statement is not reach. You can also program with `try:` ... `finally:`

Comment: Any there any errors in the logs?

Comment: @NickRosencrantz - it is not all the code, but it is a chunk of ~250 lines, of which everything else works. Only this doesn't, I will add some logging lines and report

Comment: @RobertKluin - nothing in the logs at the moment, no

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched the addimg to a POST under the UploadPage, and it worked, not sure why it didnt work when coming frmo a class though